# How to use integrated Intel graphics instead of Nvidia graphics on MacBook Pro?

Tags: nvidia, intel-graphics, macbook, uefi, hybrid-graphics

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 64bit on MacBook Pro 15" 2010 (MacBookPro6,2) and I would like to use the integrated Intel graphics instead of the dedicated Nvidia graphics Ubuntu boots with on this machine.

I am booting with UEFI, not REFIT or similar. I managed to switch to UEFI with the help of this [page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFIBooting).

This wiki page also contains tips on switching to Intel graphics which include some (for me) cryptic boot commands to grub. However if I follow the guide, my display stays just black.

Currently, I am only looking for solution to use Intel graphics for Ubuntu to save power and keep my MacBook cool. Dynamic switching or stuff like that is not required.

Answer (score 0):

If you own a Macbook Pro 6,2 or 6,1 and are adventurous enough to try the current solution, you can find the code here:

http://github.com/ah-/gmux-scripts
http://github.com/ah-/ubuntu-kernel-mbp
http://github.com/ah-/gmux

There's also some documentation here:

http://github.com/ah-/gmux-scripts/blob/master/README

Here is a summary of the current situation for having hybrid graphics working on Macbook Pros 6,2 and 6,1:

http://linux-hybrid-graphics.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/apple-macbook-pro-and-linux-hybrid_21.html

Comment: Thanks for pointing me into the right direction, #130490868091234 . However that seems to be little bit to much for me right know. I am not sure if the solutions provided there work with EFI.

Comment: Make sure you follow up new developments on the mailing list:    https://launchpad.net/~hybrid-graphics-linux

Answer (score 0):

you can try using Bumblebee. It solved the problem with Ubuntu 10.10, and I think it also works for 12.04

Comment: The power management part does not work yet for the MacBook Pro. For that to work, something like gmux could be used.

Comment: Hi #silentbang. Did you try Bumblebee with EFI booting?

Answer (score 0):

To select integrated Intel GPU and turn off nVidia GPU use:

```
sudo prime-select Intel
reboot
```

This works as of May 2018 and many years before that.